# Next.js: getStaticPaths for dynamic route with catching all routes [[...slug]].js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I read the docs of dynamic routes but they didn't explain much about how dynamic routes will work with "[catching all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)".

My folder structure for this route is:

```
└──pages
   └──catalog
      └──[[...slug]].js
```

Here's my code:

```
export default function Catalog(props) {
    return (
        <Product product={props.product} />
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const productSlug = params.slug[params.slug.length-1];
    const data = await getSingleProduct(productSlug)

    return {
        props: {
            product: data.product, 
        },
        revalidate: 30
    }
}
```

My API is WP and I have product pages URI like this `/catalog/category/sub-category/product/`

So if I go to the URL `/catalog/category/sub-category/product/` it works fine with the code I shared below because I have `const productSlug = params.slug[params.slug.length-1];` which will get my slug which I can pass to the API and use the product data just fine.

But I want to work with categories too, so if I go to `/catalog/category/sub-category/` it should load the category page, and if I go to `/catalog/category/` it should load up that category page.

Even this will work with the code I have because I'm getting the last element of `params` array which is the product slug, but that's NOT always the case. Sometimes the product is without any sub-category so the URI would be `/catalog/category/product` which means I can't fix it to the third element of the array and use the other two as category slugs.

The `params` gives me an array without any key or anything and I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this in next.js

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can not achieve all the scenario in one file, You have to take create different files, one for single product, one for category, if you want to catch all in one it cab be done but you need to write code that check for all the cases and then fetch the data accordingly.

Comment: Yes I thought that too but even if I create like `catalog>[category]/[sub-category]/[product]` it will work for URL `/catalog/category/sub-category/product` but the `[sub-category]` would still need to deal with product and category page because sometimes the product URL is `/catalog/category/sub-category/product` and other times `/catalog/category/product`, the issue will still be there but not so complex, don't you think?